# parsequery is setting a single image for all the uitableviewcells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to populate an image into a cell but for some reason, it loads into other cells when it shouldn't.
I'm not sure what would be causing this.
I'm not sure, but when I scroll really quickly down it would load 
into all the imageviews when it shouldn't like so:

[image]

Is there a reason for this?
I also might try to hide the imageview once it is gone, 
but for now I will concern myself with the image loading where it shouldn't.

The Parsequery:

```
func getLocalComments(point:PFGeoPoint){
    var temp = [CommentDetails]()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let qComments = PFQuery(className: "UserCommentary")
        let qDrinks = PFQuery(className: "venueDrinks")
        if self.type == "House Parties"{
            //Query the bars
            qDrinks.whereKey("venueName", equalTo: self.id)
            qDrinks.whereKey("venueID", equalTo: self.venueName)
            qDrinks.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

            qComments.whereKey("venueID", equalTo: self.id)
            qComments.whereKey("venueName", equalTo: self.venueName)

            do{

                let qReply1 = try qDrinks.findObjects()
                if qReply1.count>0{
                    let comment:CommentDetails = CommentDetails.init(comm: "Test", ven: self.venueName, venId: self.id, owner: PFUser.current()!.username!, vote: 0)
                    var i = 0
                    while i < 2 {
                        let item = qReply1[i]
                        print(item)
                        comment.cellType = 2
                        i+=1
                    }
                    //temp.append(comment)
                }
                let qReply2 = try qComments.findObjects()
                for item in qReply2{
                    let comment:CommentDetails = CommentDetails.init(comm: "Test", ven: self.venueName, venId: self.id, owner: PFUser.current()!.username!, vote: 0)
                    comment.commentOwner = item.object(forKey: "owner") as! String
                    comment.comment = item.object(forKey: "comment") as! String
                    comment.isFile = item.object(forKey: "image") as! Bool

                    if comment.isFile {
                        let dataPhoto:PFFile = item.object(forKey: "imgFile") as! PFFile
                        let imageData:NSData = try dataPhoto.getData()
                        let image:UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData as Data)!
                        comment.imageFile = image
                        comment.cellType = 2
                    }
                    temp.append(comment)
                }
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(temp)
            self.commentList.removeAll()
            self.commentList = temp
            self.commentTableView.reloadData()

        }

    }


}
```

The tableview:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
    var cell:commentTableViewCell
    if commentList[indexPath.row].cellType == 1{
        //drink
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "drink",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.drinkName.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.drinkPrice.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment
        return cell
    }
    else{
        //comment
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "comment",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.ownerTitle.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.commentContent.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment
        if commentList[indexPath.row].isFile{
            cell.imageView!.image = commentList[indexPath.row].imageFile
        }
        return cell
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return commentList.count
}
```

Update:

I added a hidden element as follows:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
    var cell:commentTableViewCell
    if commentList[indexPath.row].cellType == 1{
        //drink
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "drink",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.drinkName.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.drinkPrice.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment
        return cell
    }
    else{
        //comment
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "comment",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.ownerTitle.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.commentContent.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment
        if commentList[indexPath.row].isFile{
            cell.imageView!.image = commentList[indexPath.row].imageFile
        }
        else{

            cell.imageView!.isHidden = true
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Now all images are gone:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `cell.imageView!.image = nil` in `if commentList[indexPath.row].cellType == 1` index.  try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
    var cell:commentTableViewCell
    if commentList[indexPath.row].cellType == 1{
        //drink
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "drink",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.drinkName.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.drinkPrice.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment
          cell.imageView!.image = nil
        return cell
    }
    else{
        //comment
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "comment",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.ownerTitle.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.commentContent.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment
        if commentList[indexPath.row].isFile{
            cell.imageView!.image = commentList[indexPath.row].imageFile
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: actually still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a *solid* solution with larger sets but I'm willing to make this an answer and have someone pick at it. So Instead of just making it hidden I would remove the imageView completely so that it wouldn't even consider loading. It would look like so:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
    var cell:commentTableViewCell
    if commentList[indexPath.row].cellType == 1{
        //drink
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "drink",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.drinkName.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.drinkPrice.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment

        return cell
    }
    else{
        //comment
        cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "comment",for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
        cell.ownerTitle.text = commentList[indexPath.row].commentOwner
        cell.commentContent.text = commentList[indexPath.row].comment
        if commentList[indexPath.row].isFile{
            //cell.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            cell.imageView!.image = commentList[indexPath.row].imageFile
        }
        else if !commentList[indexPath.row].isFile {
            cell.imageView!.image = nil
            cell.imageView!.removeFromSuperview()

        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Now If I can find a way to properly resize the image